# Can a PDF Embed onmousedown Javascript Events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, pdf-generation, onmousedown

My client has some web pages that have A tag links with `onmousedown` events on them. My tools are PHP, Linux, and the tools for PDF generation there like [DomPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) and [PHP PDF](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-create-action.php). Is there a way to put the links into a PDF with the `onmousedown` Javascript code still working? The `onmousedown` events change the href.

I mean, I hear that PDF files can have Javascript in them, but I don't know if that also means the `onmousedown` event can be included as well and still operate.

Comment: Why not just link to the intended target? Is the URL being intentionally obfuscated? Or are you attempting to send the user to a different location on each click?

Answer (score 0):

Current stable releases of dompdf ignore JavaScript when rendering a document. The next release (0.6.0) will include the capability of including JavaScript in the rendered document, but the JavaScript has to be contained inside a script element that is in the body of the document. Because of this requirement you would have to write a function that locates your link and appends onmousedown events.

I don't know enough about using JavaScript in PDF document to say how easy it would be to write a script to do what you want.